# Web API, OData, EF5, Union: The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument

Tags: linq, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a Web API prototype using the OData Nuget package.
I'm having some issues getting a LINQ to EF query to work.

[Here are my data model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcy6o.jpg) It has been highly simplified.

I'm trying to get the query to work using this DTO:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
    var productA = _context.ProductA
                            .Select(p => new Product
                                {
                                    Id = p.id,
                                    Name = p.name,
                                    Orders = p.ProductAOrders.Select(o => new Order
                                        {
                                            Id = o.OrderId,
                                            Date = o.Orders.Date,
                                        })
                                });

    var productB = _context.ProductB
                            .Select(p => new Product
                                {
                                    Id = p.Id,
                                    Name = p.Name,
                                    Orders = p.ProductBOrders.Select(o => new Order
                                        {
                                            Id = o.OrderId,
                                            Date = o.Orders.Date,
                                        })
                                });

    return productA.Union(productB);
}
```

When trying to Union the two queries I get this error:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.
Parameter name: argument</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.ValidateDistinct(DbExpression argument)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnionTranslator.TranslateBinary(ExpressionConverter parent, DbExpression left, DbExpression right)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.BinarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.ToString()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.ToString()
   at System.Convert.ToString(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionDescriptorTracer.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;b__2(TraceRecord tr, Object value)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1b`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1f.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsync&gt;b__13(TraceRecord traceRecord)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter.Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, Action`1 traceAction)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1b`1.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsync&gt;b__12(TResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3b`2.&lt;Then&gt;b__3a(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)
</StackTrace></Error>
```

I can return either productA or productB - but returning a Union of these 2 queries result in the distinct error above.

Any ideas to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: does it work if you remove the Orders property from both projections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an EF bug. I assume you are trying to get MEST (multiple entity sets of same type) working. Instead of the query that you had, you can try,

```
public IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
    var productA = _context.ProductA
                            .Select(p => new Product
                            {
                                Id = p.id,
                                Name = p.name,
                            });

    var productB = _context.ProductB
                            .Select(p => new Product
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                Name = p.Name,
                            });

    return
        productA
        .Union(productB)
        .Select(p => new Product
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            Orders = _context.Orders
                    .Where(o => o.ProductA.Id == p.Id || o.ProductB.Id == p.Id)
                    .Select(o => new Order
                    {
                        Id = o.OrderId,
                        Date = o.Orders.Date,
                    })
        });
}
```

The idea is to take the navigation properties out of the union and add them later back. This would work only if Orders had back pointer to ProductA or ProductB.

Comment: opened the following [issue](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/972) on the EF team to track the original query issue.

Comment: How can orders have back pointer to ProductA or ProductB?

From data model ProductA and ProductB are connected to an order through ProductAOrders and ProductBOrders.

I'm not sure how to create the suggested pointer?

Comment: Accepting this answer as the issue you reported on the EF team helped me workaround this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be by design (or a limitation). For set operations (UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT) we only allow model types and "flat" transient types (i.e. row types (e.g. created for projections) without collection properties).
The workaround here would be to do the union on the client by enforcing query execution i.e. instead of doing this:

```
var query3 = query1.Union(query2);
```

do this:

```
var query3 = query1.ToList().Union(query2);
```

Comment: But this sadly doesn't work when using EF together with Web API and OData.
I need to return an IQueryable for OData to work.

Comment: The above results in two queries. I have not used Web API with OData (only used WCF Data Services) but I think it should be possible to send two queries and union them (or even just process them one by one in the same way) on the client.

Comment: From what I understand the QData query options from the URL are applied to the LINQ expression before querying the SQL server.
If I do a .ToList() all row will be fetched into memory and then the filtering will happen on the client.
Using IQueryable and OData the filtering happens on the SQL server and you will only get returned what you asked for.
I have more than 1000000 rows in both entities so getting them all into memory to do the filtering would not be the way to go.

Comment: .ToList() will enforce fetching data indeed. However if you have 1000000 rows trying to process them on the client seems wrong as well. You should use the filter in both cases so that you materialize only entities you need and not everything. The difference between having .ToList() and not having .ToList() is do I materialize my entities before processing or I process them in streaming fashion. In both cases you want to have as few entities as possible. At the moment - in your case - it is not possible to do it in streaming fashion.

Answer (score -1):

Just tried this query... it seems to be the only way using the navigation properties.

```
var productA = _context.ProductA
                .Select(p => new Product
                {
                    Id = p.id,
                    Name = p.name,
                });

var productB = _context.ProductB
                .Select(p => new Product
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                });

return
    productA
    .Union(productB)
    .Select(p => new Product
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            Orders =   _context.ProductAOrders
                    .Where(x => x.ProductAId == p.Id)
                    .Select(o => new Order
                    {
                        Id = o.ProductAId,
                        Date = o.Orders.Date
                    })
                    .Union( _context.ProductBOrders
                            .Where(x => x.ProductBId == p.Id)
                            .Select(o => new Order
                            {
                                Id = o.ProductBId,
                                Date = o.Orders.Date
                            }))
        });
```

It result in this error:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The type 'API.Models.Product' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateInitializerMetadata(InitializerMetadata metadata)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding&amp; binding)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression&amp; source, DbExpressionBinding&amp; sourceBinding, DbExpression&amp; lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.ToString()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.ToString()
   at System.Convert.ToString(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionDescriptorTracer.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;b__2(TraceRecord tr, Object value)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1b`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1f.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsync&gt;b__13(TraceRecord traceRecord)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter.Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, Action`1 traceAction)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1b`1.&lt;TraceBeginEndAsync&gt;b__12(TResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3b`2.&lt;Then&gt;b__3a(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)</StackTrace></Error>
```

I cannot understand why 'API.Models.Product' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query.

If I replace

```
        Orders =   _context.ProductAOrders
                .Where(x => x.ProductAId == p.Id)
                .Select(o => new Order
                {
                    Id = o.ProductAId,
                    Date = o.Orders.Date
                })
                .Union( _context.ProductBOrders
                        .Where(x => x.ProductBId == p.Id)
                        .Select(o => new Order
                        {
                            Id = o.ProductBId,
                            Date = o.Orders.Date
                        }))
```

With this (to make things simpler) I get the same error

```
        Orders = _context.Orders.Select(o => new Order
            {
                Id = o.Id,
                Date = o.Date
            })
```

Seems LINQ to EF is not my best friend these days :)

Comment: Found the issue...
Need to use ".Select(p => new {}" instead of ".Select(p => new Product{}" in the first 2 LinQ statements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2188206/urban can you provide your solution for this